# Covariance and contravariance not working when assigning anonymous method to delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, covariance, contravariance, anonymous-methods

I have the following code, taken from [this MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates):

```
public class First { }  
public class Second : First { }  
public delegate First SampleDelegate(Second a);

// Matching signature.  
public static First ASecondRFirst(Second first)  
{ return new First(); }  

// The return type is more derived.  
public static Second ASecondRSecond(Second second)  
{ return new Second(); }  

// The argument type is less derived.  
public static First AFirstRFirst(First first)  
{ return new First(); }  

// The return type is more derived   
// and the argument type is less derived.  
public static Second AFirstRSecond(First first)  
{ return new Second(); }

SampleDelegate test;
test = ASecondRFirst;
test = ASecondRSecond;
test = AFirstRFirst;
test = AFirstRSecond;
```

This all compiles fine but I wanted to test assigning the delegate to an anonymous lambda expression:

```
test = (First x) => { return new Second(); };
```

However on that line I get the error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'SampleDelegate' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types`

Namely: `Parameter 1 is declared as type 'ConsoleApp1.First' but should be ConsoleApp1.Second'` ("ConsoleApp1" is the name of the project).

I cannot understand what's wrong with my lambda.

Obviously covariance and contravariance and antivariance and whatnot are working OK, it seems to be just a problem with my lambda.

Comment: `First()` is a bad name for a class.  It will conflict with the Linq function `First()` (or at least it did in my brain trying to read the code).

Comment: @Neil, oh, sorry - didn't think of that. But please keep in mind this is just an application to test covariance and contravariance in delegates. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be the boring person who gives the answer "because that's what the spec says" (TL;DR at the end with my thoughts)...

Basically, it's because method group conversions (e.g. assigning a method to a delegate) and anonymous function conversions (e.g. assigning a lambda to a delegate) follow different rules, and only the former benefit from variance.

(Note that a `Method Group` means a group of 1 or more overloads of the same method - so your single methods still count as individual method groups)

Section 6.5 of the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) talks about Anonymous function conversions:

> An anonymous-method-expression or lambda-expression is classified as an anonymous function (§7.15). The expression does not have a type but can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type. Specifically, an anonymous function F is compatible with a delegate type D provided:
>
> - ...
> - If F has an explicitly typed parameter list, each parameter in D has the same type and modifiers as the corresponding parameter in F.

Section 6.6 however talks about Method group conversions:

> An implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from a method group (§7.1) to a compatible delegate type. Given a delegate type D and an expression E that is classified as a method group, an implicit conversion exists from E to D if E contains at least one method that is applicable in its normal form (§7.5.3.1) to an argument list constructed by use of the parameter types and modifiers of D, as described in the following.
>
> The compile-time application of a conversion from a method group E to a delegate type D is described in the following. Note that the existence of an implicit conversion from E to D does not guarantee that the compile-time application of the conversion will succeed without error.
>
> - A single method M is selected corresponding to a method invocation (§7.6.5.1) of the form E(A), with the following modifications:
>
>   - The argument list A is a list of expressions, each classified as a variable and with the type and modifier (ref or out) of the corresponding parameter in the formal-parameter-list of D.
>   - The candidate methods considered are only those methods that are applicable in their normal form (§7.5.3.1), not those applicable only in their expanded form.

So the method group -> delegate conversion uses more or less the same rules as if you had tried to invoke the method with the corresponding parameter types. We're directed to Section 7.6.5.1, which directs us to Section 7.5.3.1. This gets complex, so I'm not going to paste it verbatim here.

Interestingly, I couldn't find the section on delegate covariance, only interface covariance (although section 6.6. says mention it in an example).

---

TL;DR, when you write:

```
SampleDelegate test = SomeMethodGroup;
```

the compiler goes through a whole algorithm to pick a suitable member of the method group which is compatible with the delegate type, following much the same rules as overload resolution if you were invoking the method.

When you write:

```
SampleDelegate test = (First first) => new Second();
```

the compiler follows a much simpler rule of "does the lambda's signature match the delegate signature".

I suppose this makes sense. Most of the time you're going to be writing:

```
SampleDelegate test = first => new Second();
```

and it's up to the compiler to figure out the parameter types from the delegate signature. If you add in explicit types yourself, that doesn't completely change the algorithm used: the compiler uses the same algorithm, but if the types it comes up with conflicts with your explicit types, you get an error.

---

Note that almost all of the time this ***doesn't matter***. It's rare to put types on a lambda's parameters, so you'd normally just write this:

```
SampleDelegate test = x => new Second();
```

The compiler infers that `x` actually a `Second`, and that's fine: if you've written a lambda which can work if `x` is a `First`, it should also work if `x` is a `Second` (LSP notwithstanding). Notice that you're allowed to get away with returning a `Second` even though `SampleDelegate` returns a first: the compiler doesn't mind.

Comment: Did... did you read my question, at all? Maybe I need to put up a big flashing sign "contravariance and covariance not working with lambda" but I am very explicitly assigning the `AFirstRSecond` method (note that it's not a group) to the variable `test`, yet I cannot assign a lamdba **with the same signature**.

Comment: @J.Doe No need to be rude. Your `SampleDelegate` takes a `Second` and returns a `First`. You lambda takes a `First` and returns a `Second`. They have different signatures. My answer explains why you can do the assignment with a method group, but not with a lambda. Specifically, the conversion of a method group to a delegate follows different rules to the assignment of a lambda to a delegate.

Comment: Sorry if I was rude but at this pace we are getting into a "Did YOU?" loop. My `SampleDelegate` takes a `Second` and returns a `First`. My `AFirstRSecond` takes a `First` and returns a `Second`. My lambda takes a `First` and returns a `Second`. But you will notice `test = AFirstRSecond` is fine but `test = (lambda)` is not.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, I know. Like I said, `test = AFirstRSecond` is a method group conversion, and follows rules in section 6.6. `test = (lambda)` is an anonymous function conversion, and follows _different_ rules in section 6.5. I included my thoughts on why I think they follow different rules.

Comment: @J.Doe There is different behaviour because you're doing different things, and the specification says that different rules are followed in those two different cases. My answer says that, states the rules concerned, and offers my thoughts on why these two cases follow different rules. I'm not sure what else I can add.

Comment: So a single method still obeys method group logic? I.e. short answer - methods can benefit from covariance and contravariance more than lambdas can? I just thought a single method does not obey method *group* rules.

Comment: Yes - a single method is still a "method group" in the terminology of the spec. And yes, method groups benefit from variance where lambdas don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! I apologize for my rudeness, it seems **I** was the one at fault all along!

Comment: No problem - I'll add a summary at the beginning to clarify.

Comment: @J.Doe In hindsight I could have said more explicitly at the beginning that only method groups benefit from variance, which may have helped avoid the confusion. I've added it now.